# Why is $O(\log_{M/B} N/M)$ the same as $O(\log_{M/B} N/B)$?

Tags: asymptotics, arithmetic

Where $N$ is the size of the input, $M$ is the size of your main memory and $B$ the amount of elements that you can transfer in one I/O.

My idea is that since $B$ is usually much smaller than $M$ we can have

$O\left(\frac{N}{B}\log_{\frac{M}{B}}\frac{N}{M}\right) = O\left(\frac{N}{B}\log_{\frac{M}{B}}\frac{NB}{MB}\right)$

so $\frac{B}{M} <1$

but I'm new to complexity theory so I'm not sure if it's the correct reasoning.

Comment: Do you have a published source you're referencing that tells you they are the same? As I see it, $O(N/M) \subseteq O(N/B)$, with equality only if $M \in O(B)$. As you note, $M \in \Omega(B)$.

Comment: jbapple sorry for not replying earlier, this was actually written on some lecture notes.

Comment: I'll note that this question has nothing to do with algorithms or complexity theory: it's about rules of arithmetics and maybe the definition of Landau notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction will work just fine:
$$\begin{align}
\log_{M/B}\frac{N}{M}&=\log_{M/B}\frac{NB}{BM}=\log_{M/B}\frac{N}{B}\cdot\frac{B}{M}\\
 &= \log_{M/B}\frac{N}{B}+\log_{M/B}\frac{B}{M}\\
 &= \log_{M/B}\frac{N}{B}-1
\end{align}$$
Since the two terms differ by 1, they're asymptotically equal.

Comment: amazing, thank you! Informally though, could we also use the argument I used?

Comment: @jsguy. Yes. Your idea was even tidier than my original answer. See the edited version.